# Receieved msg_Image getting distored while displaying in openCv

Tags: opencv, ros

I have published an image from one node and then i want to subscribe that image in my second node. But after subscribing it in the second node, when i try to store it in cv::Mat image then, it get distorted.

The patchImage in the following code is distored. there are some horizontal lines and four images of the same image merged.

An overview of my code is following.

```
first_node_publisher
{
        im.header.stamp = time;
        im.width = width;
        im.height = height;
        im.step = 3*width;
        im.encoding = "rgb8";

        image_pub.publish(im);
} 

second_node_imageCallBack(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
       cv::Mat patchImage;
       cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

       try
            { 
                cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8); //
            }

        catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
            {
                ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
            }


        patchImage=cv_ptr->image;
        imshow("Received Image", patchImage); //This patchImage is distored
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with your encoding setting, are you sure the encoding is actually rgb8? That is unlikely because OpenCV stores images by default in the BGR format (such as `CV_8UC3`). It is also possible that your images are actually not even stored as unsigned characters, but shorts, floats, doubles, etc.

I always include `assert(image.type==CV_8UC3)` in my publishers to make sure the encoding is correct